# Redux Toolkit Query - Access cached data inside a queryFn

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a an application using Redux Toolkit Query and I want to get data of a "complex object" from the RTK Query cache before I send a query to the database and get new data.

The reason for this is that I store a complex object in an object database and want to compare the object on the client with the object fetched from the server to see what has changed and then combine any local changes with the changes from the server.

After that, I want put the now updated complex object back into the cache.

Is this possible and can you provide some sample code and documentation based on the below code?

I have already looked at the documentation, but cannot really find anything useful.

Sample code:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const complexObjectStorageApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'complexObjectStorageApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  tagTypes: ['ComplexObject'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getRiskAnalisysAndActionYearsForLoggedInCustomer: builder.query({
      queryFn: async (id) => {
        //Get cached object from the Redux Toolkit Store
        //Please provide sample code on how to do this! Should return the current complexObject in the cache.
        //Please include imports of any needed functions!
        const complexObjectFromCache = await getComplexObjectFromCache(id);

        //Get the complex object from DB. I already have this function.
        const getComplexObjectFromDB = await getComplexObjectFromDB(id);

        //This function is out of scope for the questin, but compares the complexObject from the cache with the complex object from the DB and returns an updated complexObject.
        const updatedComplexObject = await compareAndUpdateComplexObject(complexObjectFromCache, getComplexObjectFromDB);

        //Put the updatedComplexObject back into the cache
        //Please provide sample code on how to do this! Should return true if the operation was successful.
        //Please include imports of any needed functions!
        cacheUpdateResult = await putComplexObjectInCache(updatedComplexObject);

        //Put the updated complex object back to the DB. I already have this function.
        dbUpdateResult = updateComplexObjectInDB = await updateComplexObjectInDB(updatedComplexObject);

        return { data: updatedComplexObject};
      },
      //Set tag that will be invalidated
      providesTags: ( result, id ) =>
        // is result available?
        result
          ? // successful query
            [
              { type: 'ComplexObject', id: id },
            ]
          : // an error occurred, but we still want to refetch this query when `{ type: 'ComplexObject', id: id }` is invalidated
            [
              { type: 'ComplexObject', id: id }
            ],
    })
  })
})
```